# checkboxselectionmodel in EXTJS 3.4

Tags: extjs3

I am using `checkboxselectionmodel` in `EXTJS 3.4`. How to find out when the header checkbox is checked?

**Example:**

```
if (header checkbox is checked) {
    //do this..
} else if (individual child checkboxes are checked) {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Solution for my query might help someone else :)

```
var view = Ext.getCmp('<<Grid ID >>').getView();
var isChecked = false;
var chkdiv = Ext.fly(view.innerHd).child(".x-grid3-hd-checker-on");
if (!(chkdiv == null)) {
    isChecked = chkdiv.hasClass('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
}
if (isChecked) {
    console.log('Header Checked!!!');
}
else {
    console.log('Child Checked!!!');
}
```